# How to detect and convert a no-iterable parameter to iterable one

Tags: python-3.x, iterable

I have a Python function which accepts vector like parameter, but I would like that if somebody calls the function with a no iterable parameter, the function accepts and treat it like an one-element vector.

For example, a function which returns the size of a vector:

```
def longitud(v):
    return len(v)

y = [1,2]
print(longitud(y))  # it will return 2, OK

x = 1
print(longitud(x))  # ERROR
```

It will produce an error because `x` is no iterable. I would like that `longitud` function could accept both parameters without problems, and in the 2nd case, treat `x` like an one-element vector. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
def longitud(*v):
    return len(v)

y = [1,2]
print(longitud(*y))  # it will return 2, OK

x = 1
print(longitud(x))  # No ERROR
```

Alternative(check if the parameter is iterable or not if not then return 1) -

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def longitud(v):
    if isinstance(v, Iterable):
        return len(v)
    return 1
    

y = [1,2]
print(longitud(y))  # it will return 2, OK

x = 1
print(longitud(x))  # NO ERROR
```

Comment: The 2nd option is suitable to my problem because the function accepts whatever an vector or just a single element. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) @AliRojas